# Value for infobox null on only a few markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get multiple values for each marker through Google places, It is working but for some reason half the markers gives a null value for details and I am not sure why.

```
function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  var request = { reference: place.reference };
  service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  });
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6mjkLpx/

Comment: Probably because there is no data for that entry.  Which entries are you having an issue with?

Comment: When I use another method                                                               `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });`                                                                                                                 It will show data on all those markers So I know theres something there

Comment: Not sure why you are using `getDetails` with `nearbySearch`, is there some field that is not in that response that you need?  If you were using `radarSearch` most of the fields are missing, but with `nearbySearch` more of them are there in the initial response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into the query limit.  You should only request the details when the marker is clicked (and to avoid the "undefined" text in the infowindow you should check for existence on the field before adding it to the infowindow):

```
function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
        var request = {
            reference: place.reference
        };
        service.getDetails(request, function (details, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var infoContent = "";
                if (details.name) infoContent += details.name + "<br />";
                if (details.formatted_address) infoContent += details.formatted_address + "<br />";
                if (details.website) infoContent += details.website + "<br />";
                if (details.rating) infoContent += details.rating + "<br />";
                if (details.formatted_phone_number) infoContent += details.formatted_phone_number + "<br>";
                infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
            } else {
                infowindow.setContent("request failed, status=" + status);
            }
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6mjkLpx/1/)

code snippet:

```js
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: pyrmont,
  zoom: 15
});

var request = {
  location: pyrmont,
  radius: 500,
  types: ['store']
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
    var request = {
      reference: place.reference
    };
    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var infoContent = "";
        if (details.name) infoContent += details.name + "<br />";
        if (details.formatted_address) infoContent += details.formatted_address + "<br />";
        if (details.website) infoContent += details.website + "<br />";
        if (details.rating) infoContent += details.rating + "<br />";
        if (details.formatted_phone_number) infoContent += details.formatted_phone_number + "<br>";
        infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
      } else {
        infowindow.setContent("request failed, status=" + status);
      }
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I assumed it had something to do with reaching a query but I wasn't sure how to go about it.